# Plotting Separate Colors for Categorical Variable

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting quantity of a product bought versus household income. For each product bought I have a 'FALSE, TRUE' variable that indicates whether a coupon was used. I would like to change my plot so that if a coupon was used the plot will be green. How do I go about doing this? This should be simple but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

```
plot(quantity ~ household_income, data=blank, pch=19, col="blue",
     xlab="Household Income", ylab="Quantity Bought", col=2[usecoupon[TRUE]])
```

Comment: You should provide more context: what language or plotting library you are using?

Answer (score 2):

First off you need to only use one `col` parameter. If the `usecoupon` vector is in the dataframe `blank` then this should work:

```
plot(quantity ~ household_income, data=blank, pch=19,  
      xlab="Household Income", ylab="Quantity Bought", 
     col=c("red", "green")[1+blank$usecoupon]) 
   # add one to the 0/1 of a logical vector and use as index into a red/green choice
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely didn't help that I have col twice. However, that did not fix the problem. There are no errors returned but the graph is blank.

Comment: plot(quantity ~ household_income, data=blank,  
      xlab="Household Income", ylab="Quantity Bought")

points(blank$household_income[usecoup=="FALSE"],blank$quantity[usecoup=="FALSE"], col='blue')

points(blank$household_income[usecoup=="TRUE"],blank$quantity[usecoup=="TRUE"],col='red')

Comment: Well, in the question you spelled it "usecoupon" and in the code you claim work you spelled it "usecoup". I still think the code should work if you have the correct spelling.